# Foursquare Venue Category url Icon - Access Denied

Tags: android, foursquare

I have a Android application thats use FoursquareAPI.

When i put the venues on map some requests return Access Denied

Here a example:

https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories/education/administrativebuilding_32.png

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>A25C4A76CBE89768</RequestId>
<HostId>BQQK0z2iGYhmxjUJvlTz2vUWYO4wTF8lE7g6LuS1jHXNmwT88FwvfObPqyPzWOne</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using an old URI for category photos. You can always grab the latest from https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct URL:
https://ss0.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/education/administrativebuilding_bg_32-a5eb7266e90733d01295939103fc97a9.png

All of the category images are listed [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree).